# What do I need to read to understand how git works?

Tags: git

I would like to understand the way git works from a architects point of view. How are files stored, how are versions kept and how do changes happen (branches, merges, etc.)?

I am not searching for information how to use it. (I already found a lot of pages with tutorials.) But I did not find any "behind the scenes" details, that would make me understand.

Comment: This is a good question, not sure why it is not constructive

Comment: You can refer this one : A Visual Git Reference -
 https://marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-en.html

Answer (score 37):

http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/

http://www.loria.fr/~molli/pmwiki/uploads/Main/gitmanual.pdf
Chap 7

[Git From the Bottom Up](http://ftp.newartisans.com/pub/git.from.bottom.up.pdf)

Comment: Git From the Bottom Up is *the* starting point for understanding the architecture.  Linus's talk complements it well.

Comment: Updated the links.

Comment: "Git From Bottom Up" link is broken :(

Answer (score 15):

For me, the following three resources were very, very helpful, in this order:

1. [The Thing About Git](http://tomayko.com/writings/the-thing-about-git) explained why I should even care
2. [Git Magic](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/) explained how to get started
3. [Git The Basics](http://www.jukie.net/~bart/slides/intro-to-git/intro-to-git.pdf) [pdf] explained - graphically, and in detail - what happens when I add, remove, merge, etc.

Comment: _The Thing About Git_ is both fun and informative reading.

Answer (score 5):

The [Git Internals](http://peepcode.com/products/git-internals-pdf) ebook has already been mentioned. I will point out that its author, Scott Chacon, gave [a fantastic presentation about git at RailsConf 2008](http://blip.tv/scott-chacon/git-talk-4113729) that covers much the same ground as the book.

Said Scott now maintains http://git-scm.com/, which includes the [Git community book](http://book.git-scm.com/), which is more of a usage tutorial than a technical description, but does include both a nice conceptual overview of the git data model in the introductory chapter and a detailed one in its closing chapter.

Comment: That talk from Scott has been recreated in full here: http://blip.tv/scott-chacon/git-talk-4113729

Comment: Thanks, @Gerry. I’ve updated the answer with the current link.

Answer (score 3):

The US$9 100+ page PDF book from PeepCode called [Git Internals](http://peepcode.com/products/git-internals-pdf) is fantastic.  It's well written, uses great, clear visuals and is also a quick read.  I absorbed as much free online material as I could but this book put me over the top.

Answer (score 3):

To understand how git works you need to read [**Pro Git** book, fully available online for free](http://progit.org/book/).

Written by Scott Chacon, one of the guys behind [GitHub](http://github.com/).

I wrote [my opinion about the book in a review at Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/review/R1BD5210WKXVA3/ref=cm_cr_pr_cmt?ie=UTF8&ASIN=1430218339).

Comment: +1: I am reading it for the past couple of days, everything is great so far.

Answer (score 3):

Assume we are living in a pre git era. And you want to write a version control system which
is fast and better than the existing vcs. All you need is a great idea. At that moment of time the below article would be of much help.

http://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html

Answer (score 2):

I found this site when I googled "git architecture": http://speirs.org/2007/07/19/a-subversion-user-looks-at-git

Git has a mailing list: "majordomo@vger.kernel.org&body=subscribe%20git" (http://git.or.cz/#community)

And this wikipedia article may be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)

Answer (score 2):

There's a good Google tech talk:  [Linus Torvalds on git](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8)

OK, it's not something to read but it does cover some of the Git internals and design philosophy.

Answer (score 2):

I found these pages useful :

- [gitcore-tutorial](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitcore-tutorial.html)
- [git concepts from the user manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#git-concepts)
- [git repository layout](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrepository-layout.html)

Answer (score 1):

The git source code. :-)

Comment: First I had a line in my description that said: "And please something that is shorter than the source code" :) I decided to drop it, because I thought that was somehow obvious. ;)

Comment: Nothing is ever obvious, especially when your primary target audience is primarily composed of geeks. ;-)

Comment: But, MrFox, the sources aren't that hard to read, and they *are* the best place to figure out details that aren't documented.

Answer (score 1):

[This talk by Randal Schwartz](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dhZ9BXQgc4) gave me a pretty good overview.

Comment: Here is a working link for that talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dhZ9BXQgc4

Comment: This is an updated version of that talk: https://vimeo.com/35778382

Answer (score 1):

One day I actually sat down and read the entire [Git User's Manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html). Turned out to be a good idea -- the manual is very helpful, explains a lot, and is quite clear and provides useful examples.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)#Implementation) might get you started.

I do remember encountering some documents describing some of the internal architecture, so I know that they are out there. I just can't remember where they were...

Answer (score 0):

I've found the [Git User Manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html) to be very enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

There are some interesting documents on the [Documentation/technical](http://repo.or.cz/w/git.git?a=tree;f=Documentation/technical;hb=HEAD) directory of the git source code.