# Git Repo files ending up in /.git directory

Tags: git, repository, hosting, share

I have set up my repo on my godaddy shared hosting. The commit/push from the local repo to the remote repo seemed to work, but when I commit/push files from my local repo to the remote repo, it pushes the files in the /.git folder instead of my defined directory, /devel folder where the .git and .cpanel.yml folder reside. I will sincerely appreciate any help in resolving this. See the screenshots below:

[.git folder directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPERf.png)
[devel directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6Wus.png)

Comment: Your files should NOT be inside the .git folder, instead in parallel to it.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am trying to achieve, but when I commit/ push the files from my local repo to the remote repo /devel directory, the files ended up in the /.git folder instead. Then I would manually copy the files from the /.git directory to the /devel directory.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons resources about `Git`. It may help to understand how `git`works.

- To understand how git works you might read [Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/)  book, - online for free. Author - Scott Chacon, one of the guys behind [GitHub](http://github.com/).
- [What do I need to read to understand how git works? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261557/what-do-i-need-to-read-to-understand-how-git-works)
- [The Thing About Git](http://tomayko.com/writings/the-thing-about-git) explained why I should even care
- [Git Magic](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/) explained how to get started
- [Git The Basics](http://www.jukie.net/~bart/slides/intro-to-git/intro-to-git.pdf) [pdf] explained - graphically, and in detail - what happens when I add, remove, merge, etc.
- [Git Community Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) by git-scm
- http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/
- http://www.loria.fr/~molli/pmwiki/uploads/Main/gitmanual.pdf Chap 7
- [Git From the Bottom Up](http://ftp.newartisans.com/pub/git.from.bottom.up.pdf)
- [Git Internals](http://peepcode.com/products/git-internals-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after searching Google for days. The issue was with the post-receive file in the ./git/hooks folder. I added this line of code "GIT_WORK_TREE=../ git checkout -f". This fixed the problem. Now, when I make a commit and push to my remote repo, the files are being added in the right folder (/devel). Thanks everyone.